# Can't input dot and method in html?

Tags: filetype-javascript

Here is the test.html file which in editing status:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box1"></div>
    <div id="box2"></div>
    <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
       var oBox1 = document.getElementById("box1");
       var oBox2 = document.getElementById("box2");
       oBox1

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to add `.innerHTML` in `oBox1`,why can't add it ?
If i remove the following setting in `.vimrc` ,`.innerHTML` can added at the end of `oBox1`,but i can't call auto completion with double `,`.

```
autocmd FileType javascript set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
autocmd FileType javascript inoremap  .  <C-X><C-O>
```

Paste all the setting in my `.vimrc`:

```
set nowritebackup
set clipboard^=unnamed,unnamedplus
set ruler
set noundofile
set autochdir
set tabstop=4
set sts=4
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set mouse=a
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,cp936,gb18030,big5,euc-jp,euc-kr,latin1
autocmd BufRead  +  exec "%s/\t/    /g"
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set fo+=w
set wrap
autocmd FileType * setlocal textwidth=120

autocmd FileType javascript set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
autocmd FileType javascript inoremap  .  <C-X><C-O>

set number

set guifont=Bitstream\ Vera\ Sans\ Mono\ 14
set guifontwide=Noto\ Sans\ CJK\ SC\ 14

execute pathogen#infect()
execute pathogen#helptags()
syntax on
"filetype plugin indent on
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-f>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-b>"
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=['/home/debian/.vim/bundle/vim-snippets/UltiSnips']
let g:UltiSnipsEnableSnipMate=0
" list all snippets for current filetype
let g:UltiSnipsListSnippets="<c-l>"


let g:emmet_html5 = 1  
let mapleader = ','
let g:user_emmet_leader_key = ','
let g:user_emmet_install_global = 1
set linespace=4
```

Comment: You might want to edit the Post to include the output of "`:set`" when you are editing "`test.html`" , which then will include "`filetype`" & "`syntax`" & "`omnifunc`" , active at that Exact time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `test.html` is most likely to have the `html` filetype assigned, so I wouldn't expect those two autocommands to have any effect in this context, as they would only be triggered for a different filetype.
2. "If you have to press a key for it to happen, it is not 'auto'."
3. It is not evident from the existing info *why* you expect `,,` to trigger completion.
4. With `$ vim --clean test.html`, completion is triggered by `<C-x><C-o>`, as expected. You should add your whole config to your question to help us clear this out. We are missing a lot of context, here.